# Country object is not displayed

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and Angularjs. I would like some help on how to go about this.

**Angular controller function**

```
var loadTables = function(){
            tableService.all(1,20)
                .success(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.tables = response.data;
                    $scope.towns=response.town;
                    $scope.countrys=response.country;
                    $scope.package_lists=response.package_list;
                    $scope.categories=response.categories;
```

**Laravel**

```
    $id =  Auth::user()->id;
    $packages = User::find($id)->packages;
    //$packages=$packages->paginate(Input::get('perPage'))->toArray();
    $countries = Country::lists('name', 'id');
    $towns = Town::lists('name', 'id');
    $categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
    $package_list=$packages->lists('name','id');
    $packages->load('country');



    return (['data'=>$packages,'town'=>$towns, 'categories'=>$categories, 'package_list'=>$package_list]);
```

**View**

```
<option ng-repeat="country in countrys" value="@{{country.id}}">@{{country.name}}</option>
```

1.The country values are not displayed in the view. how do i go about this.

```
<div ng-controller="tableController">
<a class="add-link btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleForm()" ng-      hide="showForm">Add Packages</a>
<table class="table table-striped breathe" ng-hide="showForm">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>About</th><th>status</th><th>Image</th>    <th>Action</th></tr>                        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="table in tables">
        <td>@{{table.name}}</td>
        <td>@{{table.short_description}}</td>
        <td>@{{table.status}}</td>
        <td><img width="120" heigth="72" ng-  src="@{{getImageSource(table.image)}}"/></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" ng-  click="editTable(table.id)">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-    click="deleteTable(table.id, currentPage, $index)">Delete</button> 
        </td></tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul class="pagination" ng-hide="showForm">
    <li ng-class="{'disabled':currentPage==1}"><a ng- click="loadFirstPage()">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{'active':page==currentPage}"><a  ng-click="loadNthPage(page)">@{{page}}</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'disabled':currentPage==lastPage}"><a ng-click="loadLastPage()">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
<form name="tablesForm" ng-show="showForm" class="col-md-4"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        Name<input type="text" name="number" ng-model="newName" class="form- control" required> 
        <em class="muted" ng-show="tablesForm.available.$pristine && tablesForm.available.$invalid">Required</em>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        Avarage Price<input type="text" name="seats" ng-model="newPrice"  class="form-control" required> 
        <em class="muted" ng-show="tablesForm.available.$pristine &&  tablesForm.available.$invalid">Required</em>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        Short Description<input type="text" name="position" ng- model="newShort_description" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    Description<input type="textarea" name="description" ng-model="newDescription" class="form-control"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Category<select  type="text" id="category" ng-model="newCategory" class="form-control" required>
    <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="@{{category.id}}">@{{category.id}}</option>
    </select>
    <em class="muted" ng-show="tablesForm.available.$pristine && tablesForm.available.$invalid">Required</em>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Country<select type="text" name="country" ng-model="newCountry" class="form-control" required>
    <option ng-repeat="country in countrys" value="@{{country.id}}">@{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <em class="muted" ng-show="tablesForm.available.$pristine && tablesForm.available.$invalid">Required</em>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Town<select type="text" name="town" ng-model="newTown" class="form-control" required>
    <option ng-repeat="town in towns" value="@{{town.id}}">@{{town.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <em class="muted" ng-show="tablesForm.available.$pristine && tablesForm.available.$invalid">Required</em>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <img width="120" height="82" ng-src="@{{newThumbnail}}" ng-show="showEdit" style="display: block;" />
    Image<input type="file" name="thumbnail" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="showEdit" ng-click="tablesForm.$valid &&addNewTable(newNumber,newSeats,newPosition,newDescription,newAvailable, currentPage)">Add new table</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="showEdit" ng-click="tablesForm.$valid && updateTable(tableId, newNumber,newSeats,newPosition,newDescription,newAvailable)">Update table</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="showForm" ng-click="toggleForm()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you returning `countrys`/what is `response.country`?

Comment: corrected that but still not showing the values in the select-option. infact not just countries but town and categories too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning countries on the response list

Try the below code:

```
return (['data'=>$packages,'town'=>$towns, 'country':$countries, 'categories'=>$categories, 'package_list'=>$package_list]);
```

Edit: as per your comments, it shows that you're returning your data as objects, not arrays. For Angular to iterate through that data, it should be stored in an array.

Comment: Thanks for identifying that but its the same case with with towns and categories. the select-option shows the slots allocated for array but no values displayed. yet on the console i see all the objects returned and the values assigned

Comment: Object { data: Array[1], town: Object, countries: Object, categories: Object, package_list: Object }1 tableController.js:43:7

Comment: The issue is that you need an array, not an object. I don't have a working experience with laravel, but my gut feeling says that you're passing objects, instead of arrays from your laravel code to the ajax request.

Comment: You must be on to something, coz i have no probleddm with the data: values just the town, categories and countries. will try fixing that and see what happens